# Best way to display large stats lists in games

Tags: lists, games, numbers, stats

I'm trying to find the best way to display a large stats list in a game.
My goal is to optimize their visualization.

Players should be able to find quickly the stat they arer looking for and its associated number.

I have 3 tests below but do not hesitate if you have any better solution (with argumentation)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe grouping your stats into logical groups can help break up the long list?

Here's my thinking:

[image]

In this way, the general category of the stat can be searched for, then the smaller detailed stats are not so difficult to find because you are searching from a smaller group.

Comment: That's a solution but what about readability and placement (numbers first, label after, or else) ?

Comment: I tried to make the distinction clear between the main stat and the more detailed stats with the vertical divider. Additionally, I think it is more legible to have the detailed stats' numbers after the label versus before; the label provides a sort of visual separation from the main stat. 

Of course, this is just my initial idea based on the info you have given here. You are free to decide what works best for your project! :)